# Error loading XNA 2.0

Tags: .net, xna

I am getting an error trying to convert this project which was made in XNA 2.0.
I have now Visual Studio 2010 with XNA 4.0.
And it throws this error while converting:

```
The imported project "C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\XNA Game Studio\v2.0\Microsoft.Xna.GameStudio.Common.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Microsoft.Xna.GameStudio.Common.targets` defines the build actions for XNA 2.0 projects.  The conversion process looks like it is trying to detect what build process is currently defined for XNA 2.0, but this is no longer relevant because there should be a corrosponding `C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\XNA Game Studio\v4.0\Microsoft.Xna.GameStudio.Common.targets` that describes the build targets for XNA 4.0 projects.

The conversion wizard is only designed to update projects from the version immediately preceding the current version.

You will need to install the XNA 3.0 and/or XNA 3.1 and perform the wizard using those XNA distributions first.

There are **many** breaking changes between XNA 2.0 and XNA 4.0. The commonly suggested action is to create a new XNA 4.0 project from scratch and import existing source files and fix the compilation errors manually.

Comment: I cant ignore, because I can't run!

Comment: @Alan you may safely ignore the error. the project converted fine, but the `targets` files almost always fail because the compiler actually replaces or builds new ones on the first build.

Comment: @etens I can't run, it says an error that it can't load the project. I can't open any file, because the project isn't openning.

Comment: @Alan I've updated my answer. I personally just skip the XNA conversion wizard and create a new project, import my existing source code, and fix compilation errors manually.